# Accessing Google Compute Engine as a different ssh user

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I ssh onto GCE and submit a job using the following command:

gcutil ssh vmName sh /bin/someScript.sh

This works fine. Now I'd like to run the job under a different user on the GCE, I tried:

gcutil ssh -ssh-key-file MY_SSH_KEY_FILE anotherUser@vmName sh /bin/someScript.sh

it didn't work throwing error: "FATAL Flags parsing error: option -s not recognized"

Can anybody tell me what's wrong in the command? or more things need to be done?

Answer (score 0):

[gcutil](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcutil/) is deprecated, you should be using instead [gcloud compute ssh](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh)

To make things easier you can try something like this :

sudo ssh -i /home/testuser/.ssh/google_compute_engine testuser@IP_address sh /script/script.sh

You need to make sure that your key for user "testuser" is added to the server in `Developers Console > Compute Engine > your GCE instance > SSH Keys`